# How do i diff two string in Laravel and pass it to a view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Im running a small wiki service were users are able to change some of the columns for old NES ans SNES games. And i keep a record of all changes. And for some time i have glanced at how stackoverflow present changes and edits and that look really cool and would probably fit my project just right!

I found [this articel from 2018](https://coderwall.com/p/3j2hxq/find-and-format-difference-between-two-strings-in-php) that makes a function and present the data in a really nice way, kinda like stackoverflow. But I cannot understand how to implement this in Laravel 7.7.1 ...

What i have done so far:

1. Add a new folder called `Helpers` in `app`-folder.
2. Create `Helper.php`
3. Autload the `Helper.php`-file by addning to composer.json

   ,
   "files": [
       "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
   ],
4. Add following to `Helper.php`:

   ```
   <?php

   function get_decorated_diff($old, $new){
   $from_start = strspn($old ^ $new, "\0");        
   $from_end = strspn(strrev($old) ^ strrev($new), "\0");

   $old_end = strlen($old) - $from_end;
   $new_end = strlen($new) - $from_end;

   $start = substr($new, 0, $from_start);
   $end = substr($new, $new_end);
   $new_diff = substr($new, $from_start, $new_end - $from_start);  
   $old_diff = substr($old, $from_start, $old_end - $from_start);

   $new = "$start<ins style='background-color:#ccffcc'>$new_diff</ins>$end";
   $old = "$start<del style='background-color:#ffcccc'>$old_diff</del>$end";
   return array("old"=>$old, "new"=>$new);
   }
   ```
5. In `GameController`, trying to iterate over the old and new values and edit them with the new `get_decorated_diff()`-helper function.

   ```
   public function show(Game $game)
   {
   $game->load(['releases','history' => function($q){
       return $q->with('user');
       }
   ]);

   $diff = $game->history->each(function($history, $key){
       get_decorated_diff($history->changed_value_from, $history->changed_value_to);
   });

   return view('game.game', compact('game'));
   }
   ```
6. Receive error from line four (4) in `Helper.php`(`$from_start = strspn($old ^ $new, "\0");`)

   ErrorException
   A non-numeric value encountered

What am I doing wrong?

#### The expected result

I have tried to read up on Laravel `each()` function, and i might have misunderstood it. But it would be cool if those values are just edited and return to the view. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Im not trying to implement SO diffing algorithm. As i said, im running a small service and just want some function to show the difference.

Comment: maybe you can try to leverage Git; i cant help you further than this but i think their diffing algorithm is as good as it gets.